# An instance to call non-static methods from static

Tags: c++, instance

I found the problem here in my code but I don't understand why it works like this. I'm trying to implement static instance to call non-static methods from static. I really need this for not well structured modules of SDK I'm using (Marmalade).

I get Marmalade's error that i'm trying to delete the object which is seems to be using at time. But if I change the line: instance.http = new CIwHTTP();
to this line: http = new CIwHTTP();
the error dissapears.

But why does it work like this? I thought the instance - it's the reference to my class like a "this" variable. Why there's so much difference here? I thought there is no any difference here between: "http." and "instance.http." but how can I do exactly the "this" reference to this class to use it inside static methods?

```
===[ HTTP.h ]===
#ifndef HTTP_H
#define HTTP_H
#include <s3e.h>
#include "IwHTTP.h"
class HTTP {
public:
    CIwHTTP *http;
    HTTP();
    ~HTTP();
};
#endif

===[ HTTP.cpp ]===
#include "HTTP.h"
static HTTP instance;
char* result = NULL;
HTTP::HTTP() {
    instance.http = new CIwHTTP();
}
HTTP::~HTTP() {
    if ( http ) {
        delete http;
    }
    s3eFree( result );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the "instance." in the HTTP constructor. Otherwise you can never have more than one instance.

Comment: but why? I don't understand at all there rules of this game :)

Comment: @JavaRunner Because the constructor for any HTTP object, will modify the http pointer inside instance. If you created `static HTTP instance2`, what do you expect the constructor to do?

Comment: I expect they will be equals to each other :) I need to create something like "this" reference to have an access from static methods to all my members.

Comment: @JavaRunner no they will not be equal. When creating `instance2`, `instance`'s http will be allocated a new object and `instance2`'s http will be invalid.

Comment: Ok but what about my actual case? Is the instance now equals to "this"?

Comment: @JavaRunner No. You need to complete some basic C++ tutorials as I don't understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: I'm just trying to call non-static methods (which almost all methods of my class) from static methods. I have only 2 static methods in my class so I need some variable to access to the member of my class. I don't need a copy of that variables I need to share variables with my static methods. I need to modify variables of my class from static and from non-static methods. I tried to re-explain it :)

Comment: So I need something like a "this" but which I can use in my static methods to modify non-static (global) variables which are placed in my class...

Comment: @JavaRunner There is no static method in the code you provide. If a static method needs to modify non-static variables, then why is it static?

Comment: Yeah sorry that code does not have any static method but I need to use it. To be honest I hate static methods but I have to use it due to my SDK which claims that some methods have to be static (callbacks).

Comment: @JavaRunner static has many different meanings in C++ dependent on the context. `instance` is a global variable accessable only in that source file.

Comment: @JavaRunner You should ask a question about how to use the callbacks from this SDK you are using, in order to get more useful answers.

Comment: I'm tried to do it but there is very small community :) so I hope I can find answer here :) Because there are absolutely common and simple static callbacks.